# Get First Line of String in PHP 5.5.9

Tags: php, string, php-5.5

I need to fetch the first line of a variable/string on a php 5.5.9 document. It looks like PHP 5.3 has the tool

```
strstr(input,"\n",true)
```

but i do not believe that it works in php 5.5.9. My string is $result and I would like to illuminate all of it except the first line, then echo the only remaining line back to the user. This should be simple and i know that I am missing something.

```
<?php foreach($results as $result): ?>


    <p><?php echo $result; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$firstLine = strtok($result, "\n");
```

Or just use `explode()` but I believe the method above is faster

```
$array = explode("\n", $result);
$firstLine = $array[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your insanely fast reply, but when I add the code I get an  Undefined variable error. Can I just define the variable as a string? or should i say $str = ''; I know its a lot to ask, but maybe you could give me a short example. Thanks a ton.

Comment: In PHP you don't need to define variables as data types. If your big string (containing many lines) is `$result` then my edited answer should work.

Comment: alright, I used the code from your edited comment and it only displays the first character of the string, rather than the whole first line. I'm 14 years old, so whatever you can help me with will be a huge step up from what I already know. Thanks.

Comment: @user3865450 did you try the second alternative?

Comment: yep, same thing happened :/

Comment: Well they cut at `\n` so your document must be formatted another way. Mind pasting the whole document you have as `$result` on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: sure, the document that is set as $result is actually a script that fetches a download link for a song off of a website. For some reason, the download link is repeated many times and I only want the first line of it. You will understand what I am trying to say after you look at the $result http://pastebin.com/xfAaawec

Comment: Both your and my first suggestion works for me, see this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/545bd4f10c998d5e657e26293d980a5807a9abb4

Comment: Sadly, I have to use Windows at work.  To get the above to work you will need to use `PHP_EOL`: `strtok($result, PHP_EOL);`  and `explode(PHP_EOL, $result);`